# Trying to read a file, actual file has the correct text, .read() shows nothing:

Tags: python

The text-file this creates has both the words "Hello World" which is what the assignment is asking. When I try to add a print(openfile.read()) line to the code I get nothing returned:

```
import os

# Complete the function to append the given new data to the specified file then print the contents of the file
def appendAndPrint(filename, newData):
# Student code goes here
    openfile = open(filename, 'a+')
    openfile.write(newData)
    print(openfile.read())
    return
# expected output: Hello World
with open("test.txt", 'w') as f: 
    f.write("Hello ")
appendAndPrint("test.txt", "World")
```

The function should return the lines "Hello World" with that statement, did I place the print code in the wrong spot?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Writing to a file which is open in read and write mode altering the structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51009492/writing-to-a-file-which-is-open-in-read-and-write-mode-altering-the-structure)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After writing to a file you have to rewind (seek)
it back to the beginning before reading

add following line before the print statement

```
openfile.seek(0)
```

Documentation of seek and its parameters
https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html?highlight=seek#io.IOBase.seek

Please note, that seek is the best and most efficient way if you want to read a freshly written file from within the same process (with or without threads)

**Addendum: (Interprocess scenario)**
However if you wanted to read the file from another process, then you had to flush the file or to close it. (flushing would be the prefered way if you want to continue reading writing from within the process.

So Imagine you had two scripts:

script1.py

```
    openfile = open(filename, 'a+')
    openfile.write(newData)

    # without next line, data might not be readable
    # by another process
    openfile.flush()
    tell_script2_it_can_read_the_file()
    return
```

script2.py

```
wait_for_notification_from_script1()
with open(filename) as openfile:
    print(openfile.read())
```

Comment: This is the cleaner way to do it, but we haven't played around with .seek yet. This answer makes sense, thank you!

Comment: I enhanced it a little for an assumed inter process scenario

Comment: It always depends on the tutor. Some want, that you use only what you learned. Others appreciate students looking ahead.

In some cases looking ahead is of course not a good idea as it defies the whole intention of the exercise. An example would be if you should implement an algorithm for educational purposes, that is already built into python

Answer (score 0):

```
import os

# Complete the function to append the given new data to the specified file then print the contents of the file
def appendAndPrint(filename, newData):
# Student code goes here
    with open(filename, 'a+') as file:
        file.write(newData)
    with open(filename, 'r') as file:
        return file.read()

# expected output: Hello World
with open("test.txt", 'w') as f: 
    f.write("Hello ")
appendAndPrint("test.txt", "World")
```

Comment: This is what I think the exercise was looking for, thank you very much! I was halfway there.. I guess a messy file.close() and right after open() would have worked too (without the with)

Comment: this will work. So it doesn't really merit a down vote. 
If reading from the same process, closing and reopening is not required.

Answer (score 0):

After writing to the file you need to close it `.close()`. Then open it again with `open('test.txt', 'r+)`.

```
import os

# Complete the function to append the given new data to the specified file then print the contents of the file
def appendAndPrint(filename, newData):
# Student code goes here
    openfile = open(filename, 'a+')
    openfile.write(newData)
    openfile.close()

    openfile = open(filename, 'r+')
    print(openfile.read())


with open("test.txt", 'w') as f: 
    f.write("Hello ")
    f.close()

appendAndPrint("test.txt", "World")  # expected output: Hello World
```